# Using Ninject to setup services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

First off, I'm new to Ninject, but whilst this question targets Ninject, it would seem to apply to DI in general.

I think I'm missing something here. Suggested solutions so far all seem to be horribly complex.

I had something like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IMyService _Service;

    public MyController()
        :this(null)
    { }

    public MyController(IMyService service)
    {
        _Service = service ?? new MyService(ModelState);
    }
}

public IMyService
{}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private ModelStateDictionary _Model;

    public MyService(ModelStateDictionary model)
    {
        _Model = model;
    }
}
```

And so I thought I'd go Ninject on it. And came up with this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IMyService _Service;

    public MyController()
        :this(null)
    {
        _Service = Locator.Kernel.Get<IMyService>(new Ninject.Parameters.ConstructorArgument("model", ModelState));
    }
}

public class MyServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override Load()
    {
        Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>(); //here
    }
}
```

It seems to me though, I should be able to change the bit where it binds (marked here) so it knows at that point to get the modelstate, rather than when I want an instance in the constructor, which requires advance knowledge of the concrete service class.

Am I worrying needlessly or is there a better way of doing this?

Simon

Comment: I think when you do the Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>(), you can append a .WithParameter(new Ninject.Parameters.ConstructorArgument()) like you have it... not sure though, as I haven't gotten there just yet with my project.

Comment: You should also inject IMyService into MyController via the constructor.  the Ninject.Web.MVC project provides a controller factory which will allow you to do this easily.  In general, if you find yourself pulling things out of the kernel manually, there might be something wrong with the design IMHO.

Comment: That's much the same approach I took in the end. I passed the ModelState into a property after the constructor injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `MyService` really need a `ModelStateDictionary` to be constructed?

I would look towards refactoring that, so that I was passing the `ModelStateDictionary` into the method I was calling, rather than requiring it for construction of the Service class.

If such a refactoring is unreasonable, you will probably want to add a layer of abstraction over the `ModelStateDictionary`

```
public interface IModelStateProvider {
    ModelStateDictionary GetModelState();
}
```

And make an implementation of that interface that can retrieve the current context's `ModelStateDictionary`, then setup the binding of that interface and change your service class to take it in the constructor:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private ModelStateDictionary _Model;

    public MyService(IModelStateProvider modelStateProvider)
    {
        _Model = modelStateProvider.GetModelState();
    }
}
```

Comment: We talked through the problem a LOT yesterday. Passing ModelState is just illustrative, but it could be anything from the calling the class. Without DI, the pattern seems quite straight forward. I guess it's the cost you pay.